# Craft commerce and invoices

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

In general what is the best practice to handle invoices from orders made in Craft Commerce ?

Comment: This is a very general question, could you get more specific?

Comment: If somebody purchases a product is there a way for the user to download an invoice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a link to download a PDF version of the invoice.

Set the path to your invoice template in the Commerce General Settings.

Then to provide a frontend link to download the PDF use `{{ order.getPdfUrl() }}`